# Is it possible to add button on FormLayout

Tags: gxt

I need to display button in the middle of the dialog that uses `FormLayout`

However when I'm adding button to such dialog, it added near standard dialog buttons (OK/Cancel etc.). I do not need to add buton there, I do need to add button in the *body* of the dialog?

I guess my problem is similar to this one http://www.coderanch.com/t/496347/GWT/GXT-Button-near-text-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AdapterField` should be used to adapt Button

from http://tutorialsjava.com/2009/08/22/no-border-around-form-in-ext-gwt/ :

FormLayout in Ext-Gwt (GXT)
When using a FormLayout/FormPanel you need to be aware of some specific properties for a Form Layout.

1. On a FormLayout only widgets that extend Field are displayed. If you want to display a widget that does not extend Field, you first have to wrap it in AdapterField.
2. When I used a FormPanel it had a border around the form even when setting .setFrame(false) and .setBorders(false) .

This is not a bug, you also need to set .setBodyBorder(false) to see no borders around a form.